# R: how to export row one by one from dataframe in R to SQL Server in every particular time

Tags: r, sql-server, loops, dataframe, timestamp

I am new to R.I have a dataframe in R with 16M rows. I want to export one by one row in SQL Server every 2 minutes

Comment: `for (rn in seq_len(nrow(x)) DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "tablename", x[rn,])` might work.

Comment: you want to export a row every 2 minutes from a 16 million row table? That will take over 60 years.. We use windows bcp to export data in bulk - https://www.sqlshack.com/bcp-bulk-copy-program-command-in-action/. you can use `system2` to then call it in R, but its a bit advanced. Alternatively you can use `sqlQuery` in the `RODBC` package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/RODBC.pdf) to send data via queries to SQL